# Vector implementation - simple replacement

Tags: c++, vectors

This is intended to be a simpler replacement of `std::vector`, written for entertainment.
It should be as fast or faster than `std::vector`, but does not need to have as many features.

It should also be simple to use.

I am looking for a review on the following:

- Bugs
- Performance
- Class/Functions/Variables Naming
- Useful features to add
- Code structure
- Anything else

Here is the header file Vector.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "../Types.hpp"
#include "../System/Memory/Memory.hpp"

namespace Core
{
    namespace DataStruct
    {
        template<class ItemType> class Vector
        {
            ItemType* VecPtr;
            UInt Capacity;
            UInt Length;

            void AllocSpace();
            void DestroyAll();

            public:
            typedef ItemType* Iterator;
            typedef ItemType const * ConstIterator;

            Vector();
            ~Vector();

            void Reserve(UInt Capacity);

            void Add(ItemType const & Value);
            void Insert(UInt Position, ItemType const & Value);
            void Remove(UInt Position);

            void Clear();
            void Free();

            UInt GetCapacity() const;
            UInt GetLength() const;

            ItemType operator[](UInt Position) const;

            Iterator Begin();
            Iterator End();
            ConstIterator Begin() const;
            ConstIterator End() const;
            ConstIterator CBegin() const;
            ConstIterator CEnd() const;
        };

        #include "Vector.cpp"
    }
}
```

And the implementation Vector.cpp, excluded from the build and included from Vector.hpp since it is a template.

```
template <class ItemType> void Vector<ItemType>::AllocSpace()
{
    if(Capacity == 0U)
        Reserve(2U);
    else if(Capacity == Length)
        Reserve(Capacity << 1U);
}

template <class ItemType> void Vector<ItemType>::DestroyAll()
{
    Iterator it = Begin();
    Iterator end = End();
    while(it < end)
        it++->~ItemType();
}

template<class ItemType> Vector<ItemType>::Vector() : VecPtr(NULL), Capacity(0U), Length(0U) {}

template<class ItemType> Vector<ItemType>::~Vector()
{
    Free();
}

template<class ItemType> void Vector<ItemType>::Reserve(UInt Capacity)
{
    ItemType* ptr;

    if(Capacity > this->Capacity)
    {
        ptr = (ItemType*)System::Memory::Alloc(sizeof(ItemType) * Capacity);
        if(VecPtr)
        {
            System::Memory::Copy(VecPtr, ptr, sizeof(ItemType) * this->Capacity);
            System::Memory::Free(VecPtr);
        }
        VecPtr = ptr;
        this->Capacity = Capacity;
    }
}

template<class ItemType> void Vector<ItemType>::Add(ItemType const & Value)
{
    Insert(Length, Value);
}

template<class ItemType> void Vector<ItemType>::Insert(UInt Position, ItemType const & Value)
{
    ItemType* ptr;
    Bool insert;

    AllocSpace();

    //If Position is beyond the end then insert at end.
    insert = Position < Length;
    ptr = insert ? VecPtr + Position : VecPtr + Length;

    if(insert)
        System::Memory::Move(ptr, ptr + 1, sizeof(ItemType) * (Length - Position));

    new((VoidPtr)ptr) ItemType(Value);
    ++Length;
}

template<class ItemType> void Vector<ItemType>::Remove(UInt Position)
{
    ItemType* ptr;

    if(Position < Length)
    {
        --Length;
        ptr = VecPtr + Position;
        ptr->~ItemType();
        if(Position < Length)
            System::Memory::Move(ptr + 1, ptr, sizeof(ItemType) * (Length - Position));
    }
}

template<class ItemType> void Vector<ItemType>::Clear()
{
    DestroyAll();
    Length = 0U;
}

template<class ItemType> void Vector<ItemType>::Free()
{
    if(VecPtr)
    {
        DestroyAll();
        System::Memory::Free(VecPtr);
        VecPtr = NULL;
        Capacity = 0U;
        Length = 0U;
    }
}

template<class ItemType> UInt Vector<ItemType>::GetCapacity() const
{
    return Capacity;
}

template<class ItemType> UInt Vector<ItemType>::GetLength() const
{
    return Length;
}

template<class ItemType> ItemType Vector<ItemType>::operator[](UInt Position) const
{
    return *(VecPtr + Position);
}

template<class ItemType> typename Vector<ItemType>::Iterator Vector<ItemType>::Begin()
{
    return VecPtr;
}

template<class ItemType> typename Vector<ItemType>::Iterator Vector<ItemType>::End()
{
    return VecPtr + Length;
}

template<class ItemType> typename Vector<ItemType>::ConstIterator Vector<ItemType>::Begin() const
{
    return VecPtr;
}

template<class ItemType> typename Vector<ItemType>::ConstIterator Vector<ItemType>::End() const
{
    return VecPtr + Length;
}

template<class ItemType> typename Vector<ItemType>::ConstIterator Vector<ItemType>::CBegin() const
{
    return VecPtr;
}

template<class ItemType> typename Vector<ItemType>::ConstIterator Vector<ItemType>::CEnd() const
{
    return VecPtr + Length;
}
```

The functions in the `Memory` namespace calls the following:

- `Memory::Alloc` -> `malloc`
- `Memory::Copy` -> `memcpy`
- `Memory::Move` -> `memmove`
- `Memory::Free` -> `free`

Comment: For being _C++_ it looks a lot like _C#_... it even has some conceptual errors from thinking in _reference semantics_ instead of _value semantics_

Comment: memcpy()/memmove is not sufficient for the general case in C++ (though you can specialize it to work for certain types). Anything that is not POD type (or standard-layout types as K-ballo more accurately calls them) will have to be copied/moved using the copy/move constructors of the type.

Comment: Even getting things as fast as std::vector will be a struggle. It is very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

The first and most obvious disadvantage of your `Vector` is that it does not satisfy the standard requirements for a *Sequence*. That means that your `Vector` cannot be used with any of the *standard algorithms* nor with 3rd party algorithms designed to work with *Sequences*. It is only useful to store elements, and nothing else.

The lack of proper *constructors/destructor* and *assignment operator* will cause crashes and leaks every time your `Vector` is used. There is a lot to say on that subject, please search for a basic *C++* rule known as *The Rule of Three* which will let you know how you should write those special member functions to achieve the proper semantics.

The next obvious drawback of your implementation is that one can only get *copies* of the elements stored in the `Vector`. This not only inconvenient, its also really inefficient. One has to make a copy of the element just to *read* it; and in order to *write* it one has to make a copy, modify said copy, remove the element from the `Vector` and then insert the modified copy. As said, this is both inconvenient and really inefficient. This would be a better approach for your subscript operator:

```
ItemType& operator[](UInt Position){ ... };
ItemType const& operator[](UInt Position) const{ ... };
```

This returns a *reference* to the stored element instead, so its possible to modify it in place if we have a *non-const* `Vector`.

Another important drawback is that the `Vector` as implemented will only work with *standard-layout* types. Simply *moving* or *copying* the underlying memory for any other kind of type may result in garbled internal values, broken invariants, or even crashes and undefined behavior.

The naming convention is strange to *C++*, it seems like something brought from a different language, perhaps *C#*. But the semantics are not the same, so as a result this `Vector` will look odd for a *C++* coder, and it will seem familiar to a *C#* coder which would be inclined to think the semantics are the ones from *C#*.

You said that *This is intended to be a simpler replacement of `std::vector`*. But if I were to replace `std::vector` with `Vector` the code would not even compile, and even if it would then the observed behavior would greatly differ. As a general rule, when you code in *C++* you should stick to *C++* conventions. The same applies for any other language as well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed review. I fixed the operator[] to return a reference and also added a const version.
I did not intend for this class to be able to replace existing use of std::vector, so I am fine with it not qualifying as a sequence. I will look further into the _Rule of Three_, did you imply among other things that the constructor should be virtual?
How does this Vector not work with storing custom class? It does not simply copy the memory but also call the copy constructor on the added elements, and then their destructor when removing them. Again thanks for your review.

Comment: Ok so because there is no copy constructor defined, and no operator=, the compiler provides their default implementation. If either of those are used, `ItemType* VecPtr;` will simply be copied and point to the same memory as the source vector. I will be fixing that, thank you.